# Ruby: Downloading image to file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, file, png

In a worker of my Rails app, I am attempting to download images for image-placeholders inside of a directory:

- dir

  - www

    - img

      - logo.svg
    - res

      - icon

        - os

          - version.png

Here is how it looks:

```
def perform platform_id
    object = ::App::Platform.find platform_id

    wrapper = File.dirname(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'wrappers', object.folder_name, object.platform, platform) # these are all local variables - don't care about them

    Dir.glob(wrapper + '/**/*') do |path|
        path = path.to_s # ?
        replace_image object, path
    end
end

def download_image path, url, image = true
    response = HTTParty.get url
    f = File.new path, 'w'
    f.binmode if image
    f.write response.body
    f.flush if image
    f.close
end

def replace_image object, path
    download_image(path, object.app.logo.url, false) if path.include?('www/img/logo.svg')
    if path.split('.').last == 'png' && path.include?('www/res/icon')
        name = path.split('.').first.split('/')
        os = name[name.length - 2]
        version = name.last
        FileUtils.rm path
        download_image path, object.app.icon_url(os, version).to_s
    end
end
```

Now, here is the problem:

Doing this ...

```
$ response = HTTParty.get url
$ f = File.new Rails.root.join('test.png'), 'w'
$ f.binmode
$ f.write response.body
$ f.flush
$ f.close
```

... works well with the rails console.

The `test.png` file contains the image downloaded from the url.

The code in the worker though just puts `�PNG` into every `.png` file. Downloading the `.svg` file works well.

**EDIT:**

In production (on Heroku) this is working well. The issue only occurs in development.

Comment: Tell us more about the worker. Are you using sidekiq? Are you using an elastic beanstalk worker instance?

Comment: @NickM Sidekiq. That's pretty much it. It is only causing problems in this regard.

Comment: I don't think you need to use binmode for your file

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari If not using binmode, I get `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`